# IPhone PHONEGAP- Https ajax for datatype - XML

Tags: iphone, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to get XML response from a secure https URL using Jquery AJAX call...
I'm getting the following error. Can anyone help me with the issue?

```
 Unauthorized user
```

Here is my code

```
$.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : url + "?" + params,
           error : function(jqxhr, status, error)
           {
           alert(status +"....."+error);
           },
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            var xmlDoc = jqxhr.responseText;
                        alert(xmlDoc);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely need more details, but if you're sending a request to a secure url, you likely need to pass some kind of value to show you're logged in or some-such, like a cookie value.  To pass a value, you may need to use the `headers` option:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : url + "?" + params,
    headers : {"COOKIE", "userID=h3j5o273h4"},
       error : function(jqxhr, status, error)
       {
       alert(status +"....."+error);
       },
    success : function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        var xmlDoc = jqxhr.responseText;
                    alert(xmlDoc);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes...the params value will be user id appended with password...    var params = "usrid=" + usrid + "&pwd=" + pwd;                            folloewd by  error : function(jqxhr, status, error)
        {
        alert("failed with error" + error.msg);
        },
        headers : {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "some https:// url"},                                                                 but i'm getting error as "failed with error undefined"             plz do suggest